# How to filter the events based on the tags entered?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

Hi friends I have the models as following.

```
class Event(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, null=False)
 event_category = models.ForeignKey(EventCategory, null=False)
 event_type = EventTypeEnumField(max_length=10, blank=True, choices=EVENT_TYPE )
 title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
 description = models.CharField(max_length=160)
 created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True

class Tags(models.Model):
 event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

An event can have multiple tags, suppose event1 have tags 'x','y','z' and event2 have 'x', 'y' etc.. Now how to filter the events that have 'x' and 'y'.,further we should be able to filter for even more tags not only 'x' and 'y'. How to write the query in django for this?

Comment: Since a `Tags` can point to several `Events`, you need yo use `ManyToManyField` instead of `ForeingKey` for `Tags.event` attr

Comment: If I use ManytoManyField how to fill the data into that table while creating the event?

Comment: `e1=Event(title='event1'); e1.save(); t1=Tags(name='x'); t1.save(); t1.event.add(e1)`

Comment: @juliocesar
Ok, now I am able to create tags for different events and also able to update them. And now how to get the events with tagnames = [some set of tags here];list = Event.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[some set of tags here])
what the above query gives me?Is it correct to use this query?

Comment: lets say we have x and y tags for event1 and tag x for event2 I want event which is having x and y tags which should give me event1 but it is giving me event1 and event2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41516/discussion-between-juliocesar-and-user2936254)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return events given a list of tags names, use as in the following example:

```
tags = ['x', 'y']
events = events = Event.objects.all()
for tag in tags:
    events = events.filter(tags__name=tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Event.objects.filter(tags__name='x').filter(tags__name='y')
```

Comment: Hi Rohan, what if I need to filter based on more tags?